# How to initialize weight for convolution layers in Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I followed this [tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) for implementing Tensorflow Object Detection API.

The preferred way is using pretrained models.

But for some cases, we need to train from scratch.

For that we just need to comment out two lines in the configuration file as

```
#fine_tune_checkpoint: "object_detection/data/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.ckpt"
#from_detection_checkpoint: true
```

If I want to initialize weight with Xavier weight initialization, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [configuration protobuf definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/protos/hyperparams.proto#L76), there are 3 initializers you can use:

- TruncatedNormalInitializer truncated_normal_initializer
- VarianceScalingInitializer variance_scaling_initializer
- RandomNormalInitializer random_normal_initializer

The VarianceScalingInitializer is what you are looking for. It is general initializer which you can basically turn into Xavier initializer by setting `factor=1.0, mode='FAN_AVG'`, as stated in [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/variance_scaling_initializer).

So, by setting the initializers as

```
initializer {
    variance_scaling_initializer {
        factor: 1.0
        uniform: true
        mode: FAN_AVG
    }
}
```

in your configuration, you obtain Xavier initializer.

But also, even if you need to train on new data, consider using pretrained network as initialization instead of random initialization. For more details, see [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-train-your-model-dramatically-faster-9ad063f0f718).

Answer (score 0):

The [mobilenet_v1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/models/ssd_mobilenet_v1_feature_extractor.py) feature extractor imports the backbone network from research/slim/nets:

```
25:   from nets import mobilenet_v1
```

The code of mobilenet instantiates the layers according to the [specification](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py#L124) like this:

```
net = slim.conv2d(net, depth(conv_def.depth), conv_def.kernel, stride=conv_def.stride, scope=end_point)
```

See 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/mobilenet_v1.py#L264

As you can see, there are no `kwargs` passed to the `conv2d` call, so with the current code you cannot specify which `weights_initializer` will be used.

However, [by default](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/conv2d) the initializer is Xavier anyway, so you are lucky.

I must say that training and object detection model without pre-training the feature extractor on some auxiliary task may simply fail.

Comment: I'm afraid he wants to use the Object Detection API, and not directly the mobilenet, and there the training parameters are not set using the source code.

Comment: Yes my training from scratch failed. But I did the same thing initialization with Xavier using Caffe made good results.